# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: although the folder is there, when np.load

Tags: python, save

[files are there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chd7R.png)

I'm doing np.save in a file.py to save the scores of a model so they're more than ten files model_1_score.npy, model_2_score.npy, ... 
in the (outputs folder) 
and  np.load in another file.py to load the scores for a plot 
I tried these two but didn't work

```
res = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\outputs'
res = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\outputs'
```

and the error message was

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\outputs/model_1_score.npy'

what should i do ? please help

Comment: Are you certain the file path is correct and the files exist? Can you show this?

Comment: yes I tried os.getcwd() it gave me the same file directory where i'm working and the files are there you can check the picture up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last path separator is wrong in `C:\Users\user\Documents\outputs/model_1_score.npy`. Should be `\`, not `/`.

Comment: ya i don't know what it's looking like this.. what can be the reason ??

Comment: I can't provide ut here i need an email or discord account